# Display a "USER" ACF Field on Woocommerce Orders Detail Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I hope someone can kindly help with our Woocommerce problem.

I've been stuck looking for examples on how to display an ACF (Advanced Customs Field) field on the Orders Details Page. The difference with my query to others is that the ACF field is set against user information. So in the ACF Field group, I have set "User Role" "is equal" to "All".  This works fine and the field can be seen when viewing USERS in the backend. Via the ACF plugin, it will save data against the user.

The field label is "Credit Account Status", and field name is "credit_account_status". Its a checkbox field with 3 options:
Active - No credit given
Active - Credit OK
ON STOP - credit removed; see Accounts Dept.

We want to call up this field when viewing orders on the Order Details page - maybe underneath the shipping address section at the top of the order page. We want this as a visual to prevent us raising new orders manually for someone who hasnt paid their bills on time!

Can anyone help please?

I previously tried to edit the below code, but my programming is very poor - this code seems to bring in data from Order meta, not USER meta.

```
/**
```

- Display field value on the admin order edit page..
- 
- PHP Custom Feild Value
- 
- 

*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
echo '

**'.__('Store Location').':** ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'My Field', true ) . '

';
}

Best wishes, Craig

Comment: can you specify a little more on which orders detail page? also if possible please add some screenshots.

Comment: Its the screen which you can input a NEW order or view an order inside Woocommerce. We operate the online shop on the front end, but because we receive orders by email and telephone as well, we use this page a lot.

Comment: ok, but can you tell me which specific area where you want to display it?

Comment: Hopefully you can see this here:https://ibb.co/KrjB0Dr

Comment: I have removed personal data by using the black boxes

Comment: Underneath the shipping details section of the ordr

Comment: Yes, this can be possible. but i's required custom code. what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Bhautik and others, I have revised my post above